# How to get next date from selected date in Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have used Bootstrap DatePicker plugin

Click [here](https://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=2&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox) to Check that plugin

I wanted to know how do i get the next date from the selected date in date picker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `.setDate()` function in javascript to set the next day's date once you have extracted the selected date using `getDate` from the datepicker.

---

Check my working fiddle here : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jairajdesai/t5w5u946/)

---

**Javascript/JQuery :**

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker().on('changeDate', function() {
  var temp = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
  var d = new Date(temp);
  $('#currentdate').html("The selected date is :" + d);
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
  $('#tomorrowdate').html("The next date is :" + d);
});
```

---

**HTML:**

```
<div class="input-group date datepicker" data-provide="datepicker">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <div class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="currentdate">
</div>
<div id="tomorrowdate">
</div>
```